# Is Doug pronounced dug or door-g?

Tags: american-english, british-english, spoken-english

I remember many years ago when I was in Durham, UK, people pronounce the name Doug as door-g. However, I look up the dictionary and Oxford dict online and many other sources, they clearly say that British pronunciation of Doug is dug. Is Doug pronounced dug world wide? Could somebody explain? Any corrections are welcomed.

Comment: Most Northern accents in Britain pronounce the vowel in ***hut, but, Doug[las]*** like the vowel in ***foot, root,...*** If you spent time in Durham you should have noticed that.

Comment: See [this metafilter post](https://ask.metafilter.com/149866/Irish-Dougie). I never thought of the possibility that ***Doug / Dougie*** might be diminutives of the (primarily *Scottish*) name ***Dougal*** (rhymes with ***Google***). In that case, even Southerners would presumably enunciate the diminutives using ***oo*** rather than ***u.***

Comment: How would you pronounce "door-g"? I assume that's a non-rhotic accent? Not rolling your R but is the vowel r-coloured? There's still quite a few pronunciations possible. Other words with the same vowel?

Comment: It also depends on whether their name is Douglas or Dougal.

Comment: Please use IPA. Please don't add an R to a word in your spelling pronunciations to mean something that isn't the R sound: it is opaque to most native speakers of English.

Comment: Welcome to the world of regional accents! You've first heard the name spoken with quite a strong north east of England accent, that's all. It would sound different again in parts of the north west or the south, or Wales.

Answer (score 1):

**"Doug" is almost invariably pronounced the same as "dug".** It's generally short for "Douglas" and is pronounced the same as the first syllable of that name.

The name "Dougal" is usually shortened to "Dougie" (Doo-ghee, with a hard g). A specific person might use "Doug" as a shortening of "Dougal" and pronounce it "Doog", but it would be unusual.

Any given person might decide to pronounce any of the above any way they want. But if you had to pick a pronunciation of "Doug" with no other knowledge, go with "Dug".